How to change IP address of GeoServer to connect to GeoNode on same IP address
I have been working on it quite some time. I want to set the IP address of GeoServer to what is of GeoNode so that both connect properly to upload layers and create map. GeoNode comes builtin with GeoServer. Just that we have to run commands like:
paver setup_geoserver
paver start_geoserver

and it starts GeoServer but on localhost.
I have tried to go to this file ./geoserver/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml
and change the IP address and port in it.
    <context-param>
      <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
      <param-value>http://1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver</param-value>
    </context-param>

I have also changed the .env file located in venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geonode/.env
SITEURL="http://1.2.3.4:8000"
GEOSERVER_WEB_UI_LOCATION="http://1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver/"
GEOSERVER_PUBLIC_LOCATION="http://1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver/"
GEOSERVER_LOCATION="http://1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver/"
SITE_HOST_NAME="1.2.3.4"

I also changed the Proxy Base URL present in global settings on Geoserver website. but still two problems persist.

When I go from GeoNode to GeoServer via a link present on GeoNode website, it goes to localhost:8080/geoserver. Instead it should go to 1.2.3.4:8080/geoserver
Uploading layers is working fine but when I go on create map to fetch layers to show on map then it gives error: "the layer has not been loaded correctly or not available".

Note: I am using Nginx and Gunicorn for GeoNode

You need to tell geonode what the IP address is

I resolved the issue. we don't need to set the Proxy Base URL in global settings in Geoserver site. Just that after all of the above work is done, we need to run again:
paver setup_geoserver
paver start_geoserver

if it gives error that port 8080 is already in use (because we ran paver start_geoserver before too) then kill that process and run above commands again.
then restart gunicorn then nginx:
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl restart nginx

